# Unhandled Rejection (Error): The file given is not an image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, react-redux, react-hooks

- here i am upload a file using formik in react js
- When the file is upload it's size validation works but type validation not work
- Here is my code
  If anyone can help me so it's really helpful to me

  ```
   const SUPPORTED_FORMATS = ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg","image/png"];

  const onFileChange = async (file) => { 
   const options = {maxSizeMB: 1, maxWidthOrHeight: 500, useWebWorker: true} 

   const compressedFile =await imageCompression(file, options)
     console.log(`------- Compressed File Size ${compressedFile.size / 1024} KB -------`)

     var formData = new FormData()
     formData.append('file', compressedFile)
     var url = URL.BASE + URL.STORAGE_UPLOAD + 'profileImage'
    var result = await post(url, formData, 'multipart/form-data')

    if (result.is_success === false) {
        addNotification(result.error_message, 'danger');
      }

     else{      
     var url= reader.readAsDataURL(file)
     reader.readAsDataURL(file)

      reader.onloadend = function (e) {
      setSelectedImgUrl(reader.result);
        setProfileImage(result.data.fileName);    
     }
     .bind(this)
  } }



    profileImgUrl: Yup
           .mixed()
          .nullable() 
          .notRequired()      
           .test(
                   "filesize",
                   requiredMessages.file_size_validation,
                    (file) => !file || (file && file.size <= 2000000)
                )      
           .test(
                   "fileformat",
                   requiredMessages.file_type_validation,
                   (file) => !file || (file && SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(file.type))
               ),



    <input className="fileInput hidden" type="file"  name="profileImgUrl"  id="profileImgUrl" accept="image/*  onBlur={handleBlur} onChange={(event) => { setFieldValue("profileImgUrl",event.target.files[0])onFileChange(event.target.files[0])}}/>`
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You set the Max Size on the options declaration.  You did not set the allowed Types.

```
 const options = {maxSizeMB: 1, maxWidthOrHeight: 500, useWebWorker: true}
```

Try this (would double check if it's .jpg or jpg as I can't recall the syntax):

```
const filesFormats = [".jpg", ".gif"];
const isRightFormat = filesFormats.includes(file.type);
```

Comment: i have declared support types as you say but similar error comes

Comment: Can you be more clear by what you mean?  The above check -does- work I tested it before posting.  The exception you're getting is that you're testing for a param you didn't set so it's failing the test.  Using the above code works 100%.  The code I posted doesn't "declare the support type" you need to replace the validation code you have there as well.  Make sure to declare filesFormats in a scope that can be seen by your function.  Replace SUPPORTED_FORMATS with filesFormats.

Comment: I couldn't quick google the correct way to format this via the plugin opts, but this fix does work.  Your current code is checking for approved file formats, and you haven't set any in your opts dec.

Comment: ok I edit supported formates and size as you can say, so it will be understandable

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was to explicitly set File.type to "image/jpeg"

[image: Code example]